# can't install cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Tags: laravel-7, slug, laravel-backpack

I try install  cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

```
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
```

and got error

```
  Problem 1
    - cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable[8.0.0, ..., 8.0.2] require illuminate/config ^8.0 -> found illuminate/config[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with anoth
er require.
    - Root composer.json requires cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable ^8.0 -> satisfiable by cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable[8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2].
```

How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should install sluggable version according to your laravel version. Like- run this command for laravel version 7.00

```
      composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 7.00
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable *
```